# How do I get sqlite3 to use relative path when connecting to a db?

Tags: python, flask

My flask app is unable to open a db when I use it's relative path:

```
conn = sqlite3.connect("down.db")
```

It works fine I use the absolute path:

```
conn = sqlite3.connect("C:\\Users\\Lenovo\\PycharmProjects\\spacedonline\\down.db")
```

I've tried using .\ as well.
Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: What is the output of `os.getcwd()`, and does this match the directory of the database? That aside, explicit paths are a safe bet.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the file is in the same directory as the app, you could do something like

```
import os

path = os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__)) # directory path of the app
conn = sqlite3.connect(path+"/down.db")

# or - after @S3DEV comment
conn = sqlite3.connect(os.path.join(path, "down.db"))
```

Comment: Would recommend using `os.path.join`, not `+`.

Comment: Thanks Patrick. Needed to add a "\" but other than that, worked perfectly!

Comment: ... hence one reason (among others) for the comment above.

Comment: I agree @S3DEV, its more pythonic